# find common values from json file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to find users from a JSON file that have the same "p1" as the input user, and then return the names of all of them.
I'm new to coding, sorry if this code looks bad

user1 refers to the input user

```
async def find_common_p1(user1):
    users = await get_json()
    for user in users:
        if users[str(user)]["p1"] == users[str(user1.id)]["p1"]:
            return users[str(user)]["name"]


async def get_json():
    with open("the json file", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

Inside the json file looks like:

```
{"user_1_id": {"name": "user_1", "p1": False}, 
"user_2_id": {"name": "user_2", "p1": True}, 
"user_3_id": {"name": "user_3", "p1": True}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, your code:

```
async def find_common_p1(user1):
    users = await get_json()
    for user in users:
        if users[str(user)]["p1"] == users[str(user1.id)]["p1"]:
            return users[str(user)]["name"]
```

This will return the first user with a matching "p1". To return all users with a matching "p1" you have to remember all the users who match then return it at the end of the function. So like this

```
async def find_common_p1(user1):
    users = await get_json()
    users_with_matching_p1 = []
    for user in users:
        if users[str(user)]["p1"] == users[str(user1.id)]["p1"]:
            users_with_matching_p1.append(users[str(user)]["name"])
    
    return users_with_matching_p1
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get rid of the brackets and separate the users?

Comment: For sure, which brackets are you looking to get rid of, and what do you mean by separate the users? The function will return a list of names, so the the users are separated by each user becomes a name in the list

Comment: Yeah, when I print, can I remove the [ ]? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Yes so what you're seeing is the default conversion of array to String for printing. If you want to print it in a custom format you'll need to process the array and create a string in the format you want, for example

```
Output = ""
for user in users_with_matching_p1:
     Output = Output + user + " "
print(Output)
```